# CSS - using <ol> and "float: left" for <li>: numbers are not on the beginning of the line

Tags: html, css

I am using this code structure:

```css
.pull-left {
  float: left;
}
.align_center {
  text-align: center;
}
.width_33 {
  width: 33%;
}
.cleaner {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ol class="stats">
  <li>
    <div class="pull-left width_33">
      Pete
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left align_center width_33">
      1 client
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left align_right width_33">
      <span title="Commissions">
        $28.61
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="cleaner"></div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

This is the result:
[image]

Why the "1." is not on the beginning of the line (that's where I would like to get it)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a little workaround. Use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float` and wrap the `div` elements in a wrapper div:

```
<ol class="stats">
  <li>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="pull-left width_33">
     Pete
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left align_center width_33">
     1 client
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left align_right width_33">
      <span title="Commissions">
        $28.61
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="cleaner"></div>
  </div>
 </li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
.pull-left {
 display:inline-block;
}
.align_center {
 text-align: center;
}
.align_right{
 text-align:right;
}
.width_33 {
  width: 32%;
}
```

**Note: I made each div 32% instead of 33% to prevent a wrap to the next line**

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj6nnysd/)

Comment: I tried to avoid using `display: inline-block;` (and use instead of that that `float`), but it seems to be the fastest way to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the space to the left of the first left-floated div in the li.

```css
.pull-left {
  float: left;
}
.align_center {
  text-align: center;
}
.width_33 {
  width: 33%;
}
.cleaner {
  clear: right;
}
.full {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.stats li >div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ol class="stats">
  <li>
    <div class='full'>
      <div class="pull-left width_33">
        Pete
      </div>
      <div class="pull-left align_center width_33">
        1 client
      </div>
      <div class="pull-left align_right width_33">
        <span title="Commissions">
        $28.61
      </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you @stark for the answer, however - this doesn't work properly too, the line is split in 2.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed it, trying to correct that now. :P

Comment: @user984621 : I've edited my code so that its a single line instead of a line split in 2 now.